# adapt layout to hdpi and xhdpi

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing an app and yesterday I deployed it on a galaxy S3 and galaxy S.
I know that the first one support xhdpi and the second one hdpi. 
So I also defined layout-large and layout-xlarge as I read [here (Google Site)](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
the result is that both used layout (medium). So I tried (for jocking) layout-hdpi and layout-xhdpi, and work!

I don't understand why? Any suggestion?

Moreover: I defined in my project layout-small, layout (medium), layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi and layout-large. I need to add other layout, but which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout-large and layout-xlarge correspond to the size of the screen. MDPI/(X)HDPI corresponds to the resolution of your device. Those are two different things.

Galaxy S has a screen of "normal" size and HDPI resolution, that's why it will use "layout" folder and not layout-large or anything else. It will however use layout-hdpi.

The most important thing is to provide alternative drawable for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. The layout should adjust automatically if the sizes are defined correctly (without absolute sizes, stretch to the width of the screen, etc.)

In the link you mentionned, check especially the section "Range of screens supported", it contains more information about this issue.